# Fix video files which have aspect ratio 1:1

Tags: video, conversion, aspect

I'm using VideoProc Converter to convert several video clips. The video clips are in different format. My purpose is to make all of them in same format with 1080p resolution and 30 fps.

I've noticed that a few files are showing 1:1 aspect ratio, despite the video having 9:16 aspect ratio:

[image]

On the left preview pane, you can see the aspect ratio.

The problem is, after I convert, whether I keep the resolution and aspect ratio same or whether I change the aspect ratio to 16:9, the resulting video's aspect ratio becomes 1:1 and thus the video is stretched horizontally.

How can I convert properly so that the videos aren't stretched this way?